# Mysql - Invoice, Invoiceitems and top selling products

Tags: mysql

I have a problem that I can't figure out.

I have three tables in my mySQL database. It's **Invoice**, **InvoiceItems** and **Products**.
My main goal is to calulate the top 5 selling products based on what status of the invoice.

Invoice can have status 0 or 1, 0=invoice,1=creditnote, and multiple InvoiceItems, each of the InvoiceItems is connected to a Product.

The table setup is something like this:

```
Invoice(invID, Status,++++)
-- 1,0
-- 2,1
-- 3,1


Product(proID, Name,++++)
-- 1, "Coca Cola"
-- 2, "Pepsi"

InvoiceItems(itemID, invID, proID, TotalSum)
-- 1,1,1,1000 (Selling Coca Cola for 1000 on invoice 1)
-- 2,2,2,2000 (Selling Pepsi for 2000 on invoice 2)
-- 3,3,1,400 (Withdraw/credinote Coca Cola for 400 on creditnote 3)
```

My pseudocode  is:

Get Products totalselling sum by taking
TotalSum of each Product where connected Invoice has status=0 (invoice), and withdraw TotalSum if status=1 (creditnote)

Desired output

1. Pepsi Max, "2000"
2. Coca Cola "600"

Any help that can lead me in the right direction is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT p.Name, SUM(CASE WHEN i.Status == 0 THEN it.TotalSum ELSE -it.TotalSum END)
FROM Product p
JOIN InvoiceItems it
    ON p.id = it.proID
JOIN Invoice i
    ON it.invID = i.id
GROUP BY p.id
ORDER BY 2 DESC;
```

I think this would work for you.

Answer (score 1):

The code from Ayus Mohanty was almost right, I did some changes and now it worked perfectly..

Perfecty working code:

```
SELECT p.Name, SUM(IF(i.Status ='0', it.itm_linesum, IF(i.Status ='1',-it.itm_linesum,0))) as countedsum
    FROM Product p
    JOIN InvoiceItems it
        ON p.id = it.proID
    JOIN Invoice i
        ON it.invID = i.id
    GROUP BY p.id
    ORDER BY countedsum DESC;
```

Comment: It really depends on the actual set of data. But i am glad you got the direction.